# App script - Delete a specific table in google doc

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, removechild

I'm trying to make app script to create a google doc filled in function of some given answer, given in a spreadsheet.
I've some problem to remove a specific table that is present in a google doc template that must to be copied and filled as told.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ModuloRaccoltaDati = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MRD");
  var ColonnaDaCopiare = ModuloRaccoltaDati.getLastColumn(); 
  var NumErog = ModuloRaccoltaDati.getRange(15,ColonnaDaCopiare).getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1ubPramWI890GDkcEdIoQqGxuXR0kBo6O-nOn1_gtlII'); 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ce-bya5gwwn4TQdu7hDIVmjqDajTyYhg');
  var copy = file.makeCopy(NumeroDiImpianto, folder); 
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  var body = doc.getBody();
  if (NumErog == 1) {
    var tableErog2 = body.getTables()[1];
    tableErog2.deletetable();
  }
}
```

All this creates the new doc...but doesn't work about the table removing.

Comment: Hello, did your issue get solved? Remember that if you want to mark your question as solved you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) whatever answer provided a solution to your problem by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users. If that's not the case and your issue is not solved, please consider explaining why that's not the case so that this community can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The script is not deleting the table because you are using a non-existing method to do that (`deletetable()`).

To remove a [Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table.html) from a Document using Apps Script, I can see two easy options:

- From the child: use [table.removeFromParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table.html#removefromparent), which will remove the table from its parent.
- From the parent: use [removeChild(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#removeChild(Element)) method from the parent element.

So you should be able to get this done by changing this line:

```
tableErog2.deletetable();
```

To this one:

```
tableErog2.removeFromParent();
```

Or alternatively, to this one:

```
body.removeChild(tableErog2);
```

I hope this is of any help.