# Use Google Script to Edit and Delete Tables in Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Immediately below is a function that creates a sample document and inserts three tables into it. The three existing tables appear in the log as [Table, Table, Table], with a correct count of 3. How do I "access" or "select" these tables for editing? I'd like to receive from someone the code that's needed to *add a row at the end of table 1*, and then the code *to delete table 2*. If I understand that, I think I'll have what I need.

```
function create_edit_delete_table() {

// Create sample table and get id
var docId = DocumentApp.create('SAMPLE_DOCUMENT').getId();

// Get doc body
var body = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();

// Create a two-dimensional array containing the cell contents.
var cells = [
  ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2'],
  ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
];

// Build three tables from the array and insert into document.
body.appendTable(cells);
body.appendTable(cells);
body.appendTable(cells);

var tables = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody().getTables();
var tables_ct = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody().getTables().push();

Logger.log(tables);
Logger.log(tables_ct);

//Looking for code to add a blank row to the end of first table.

//Looking for code to delete the second table.

}
```

THANKS!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. Quite a few things, actually, including adapting scripts I've found on the web. One of the examples for deleting a table is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989022/app-script-delete-a-specific-table-in-google-doc. Unfortunately, I've been unable to get it to work with either removeFromParent() or removeChild(). These functions assume that I have the table in hand, but so far I'm unable to "connect" these to the tables correctly.

Comment: Kindly ask only one question per post. Focusing on question 1, `tables` is a array. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources about js arrays. Selecting table1 is  simple as `tables[0]`. Then you'd search the documentation for available table methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append empty row to table 1. Use this:

```
function appendRow() {
  var body = DocumentApp.openById("doc id").getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  var firstTable = tables[0].appendTableRow();
  firstTable.appendTableCell();
  firstTable.appendTableCell();
}
```

To delete the 2nd table in the doc. Use this:

```
function deleteTable(){
  var body = DocumentApp.openById("doc id").getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  tables[1].removeFromParent();
}
```

Note: The sequence of the Table Object in `getTables()` array are based on the position of the table in your Docs (top to bottom) and 0 is the starting index.

Example:

**Before:**

[image]

**After executing appendRow():**

[image]

**After executing deleteTable():**

[image]

### References:

- [TableRow.appendTableCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#appendtablecell)
- [Table.removeFromParent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#removefromparent)
- [Table.appendTableRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#appendtablerow)